# Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers

Tags: discussion, migration, site-recommendation, code-review-se

[Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is becoming well-known on Stack Overflow.

The folks over on Code Review are happy about that.
The only problem is that there are a lot of questions redirected to CR which don't belong there.

So I want to ask that the users who direct askers to CR (or request migration of questions to CR) read our [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to know what is on topic.

Here is a **[handy checklist to follow](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1689/31503)** if you think a question should be migrated or re-asked on Code Review.

In a nutshell:

- Real code has to be written.
- The code has to work.
- Broken code or troubleshoot bugs is **off-topic**.
- Requests to explain others' code are **off-topic**.

Comment: is this a tag-specific or general? I have been following VBA on CR for quite a while and have not encouraged many (if any) off-topic Qs.

Comment: @mehow: In general.  We sometimes get questions that have *nothing* to do with review, which indicates that the commenter has never read the Help Center.

Comment: It probably won't fully address the problem, but maybe review-related tags on SO should be improved? I see `code-review`, `review` and `reviews`. Not sure if the latter two are for code reviews at all, since they have no description, but I've seen `review` used that way at least once. The `code-review` tag does mention that CR is for "otherwise working" code, but it's not really emphasised, and is silent on what should be done with reviews of, e.g. architecture or class structures which haven't yet been fleshed out into full code.

Comment: If I redirect OP's to another site within SE I nowadays advice them to check the helpcenter and meta of that site to verify if the question is actual on-topic. Shouldn't we have some boilerplate comment text ready for that?

Comment: It should really be responsibility of the person who is posting rather than blaming people who "attempt to help" by redirecting somewhere else within the SE Network. It's good to **make everyone aware** of help-centres and what is mainly on/off topic for each SE site but honestly, don't blame the people who are trying to help, blame the askers. Make them more aware of the rules and laws

Comment: @mehow No matter what the situation, it is of course the asker's responsibility to ensure that they are posting in accordance with the site's help center guidelines. But I don't think that absolves other people of any responsibility when they give bad advice. And from a more pragmatic point of view, if there are two factors contributing to the problem, isn't it a good idea to at least consider what can be done to help with *either* factor?

Comment: @mehow I'm not accusing people, I'm just glad people want to help redirect to the correct site.  I just post it to discuss how we can try to solve the issue. Maybe a solution can be a sister site in the picture? Every day another site. With explications what they do and the rules?

Comment: @chillworld oh I never said you were :) Just generally saying that asked should check first before posting. Ie. if someone tells you to jump in front of a driving lorry you don't do that just cause someone told you :P I like your idea about introducing other sites on the SO site

Comment: Can we have some examples of bad recommendations?

Comment: @AndrewMedico:  "What's wrong with this code?  I try [some input] but *it doesn't work.*"

Comment: As someone who finds it hard to figure out what question is on-topic based on the help-center, and often debates on when I'll and when I wont suggest asking it on a different site, I want to thank you for the link to the checklist :)

Comment: I can agree that it is the responsibility of the Asker to ensure his question is on-topic for the site he is posting his question to, if a Recommender is recommending that the question be reposted to another site, that suggests that the Asker already failed to notice his question was off-topic for the first-site.  The Asker now most likely assumes the Recommender knows better than the Asker and posts to the recommended site in the same manner in which he posted to the first site--without first checking the help center himself to assure that the question is on-topic.

Comment: Since the "handy checklist" already answers the question, why do we need this post? Also you aren't really asking a question, as much as posting an additional answer to the "handy checklist" link. I think we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: I see a fair number of "debug my code for me" questions that were migrated from codereview.  We don't want them either.  Keep in mind that you have the bigger power here; unlike codereview users, regular SO users cannot migrate questions to codereview.  Perhaps you post a similar notice to your meta?

Comment: @HansPassant: CR users cannot migrate directly to SO (or anywhere), either.  Only us mods can do this.

Comment: As OP I want to thank all who has reading this.  It really improves the migrating, and I hope also for all the other sites to.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Thanks for your advice. I'm glad I already follow those tips.

Some key-phrases that may hint to you that the question is better suited for Code Review are like the following:

> "How do I make this code shorter?"
>
> "How can I improve this code?"
>
> "This code does exactly what I want, but it's ugly."
>
> "Do you see anything wrong with this code?"
>
> "How can I make this code more Pythonic?"
>
> "Is there another way to do this other than [method]?"

Don't just act on a hint though; please also read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: "Do you see anything wrong with this code?"

Comment: @AlexandreSantos: Unless prefixed with "There's something wrong with this code."

Comment: Hey you guys ... is CodeReview suitable for the case of:  **"how do I best generalise this concept"**?  For me that goes to the absolute heart of real programming engineering - you have datable calls to parse, but you're trying to abstract it all out ... you're trying to generalise beyond one data type ... and so on .. **is that suitable** for CR site?  Cheers!

Comment: @JoeBlow it is for me. It falls under the "How can I improve this code?"

Comment: What about the keyphrase "How I can I make this code faster?"

Comment: @OllieJones: Real, working code? Preferably with an effort already made (described in the question)? Then that would fall under seeking improvements, too.

Comment: Another is "Can I make this more Pythonic?"

Comment: @AlexandreSantos Code Review is, just like Stack Overflow, **not for debugging code**. Code that is posted on Code Review should be tested before it is posted there, hence "Do you see anything wrong with this code?" is not a good question to ask.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos more like "does this code make my ass look fat?"

Answer (score 42):

When a post involving reviewing code is encountered, any of these two things can happen:

- one or more users leave a comment, telling the OP to post on CR
- one or more users flag the post for migration

As I've observed, the former causes the most problems.  Sometimes the user is not *quite* right in making the recommendation (which is understandable if it's a gray area area), and sometimes the user is dead wrong.  This is why I stress the importance of getting familiar with CR's Help Center, especially before commenting.  The OP will almost always take that advice and post on CR right away, even without reading the Help Center.  We then have to tell them that their post is off-topic there, which could leave them disappointed.  Of course, we'll have to correct the commenter(s) as well.

Flagging, on the other hand, is safer because the SO mods are the "gateway" to migration.  The other CR mods and I regularly stay in touch with the SO mods, looking over questions that have been flagged for migration.  This helps educate the SO mods more, as well as the flaggers.

At this time, it doesn't matter which you choose, as long as you're *sure* that the post should be migrated.  If you're unsure, then you don't have to do anything.  Bad migrations just create more work for us, and it's not something that should be our primary focus.

Comment: Listen to Jamal ya'all. He is the top person at code review.

Comment: Eh, far from it, but he's a moderator so at least he's got that going for him.

Comment: @BoltClock I wasn't meaning reputation wise. You have very low activity on CodeReview, otherwise you would understand :p

Comment: To clarify that point, he does so much on the site he has [become a meme on the site](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1675/42325)

Answer (score 20):

IMHO redirecting people to site X (not only when being redirected to CR by the community) on the Stack Exchange often results in a closed question on two sites.

I see it daily that people who don't have any clue what site X is about tell OP to go to site X, which looks like simply moving crap to me. This isn't really a new problem though. I have seen the moving of crap for as long as I have been on SO.

So please: people, when in doubt, post a comment telling OP it *might* be suited for site X, but *please* when in doubt or clueless **please tell OP to check the help center of site X first** before posting a question there.

Comment: When in doubt, *don't bother suggesting at all*. Saves everyone including yourself unnecessary headaches.

Comment: I can totally live  with that

Comment: yes, see that on programmers a lot. Something gets moved there from SO, then closed there as off topic with a note that it's better suited for SO. So they repost to SO and get their post closed as duplicate of their own prior post that was closed as off topic... People get ping-ponged between sites that way, often ending up discouraged.

Comment: For the reasons that PeeHaa has mentioned, I think the only sites listed for a given volunteer (who wants to close vote - migrate) should be the sites where the given volunteer has at least _n_ rep points.  This is one feature where the "trust metric" would actually be suitably coupled.  Whether the minimum trust threshold is 3K, 5K, or 10K, I don't care, but I think some privilege barrier would seem helpful in preventing garbage transfers.