# Can we move questions from Stack Overflow to CodeReview.SE?

Tags: support, feature-request, code-review-se

I see a *lot* of questions on Stack Overflow that would be more appropriate on CodeReview.SE (For example... [Understanding for loops and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550787/understanding-python-for-loops-and-functions)).

Is there anything I can do to just move the question over, where it would actually get answered in a useful way instead of being closed as off-topic?

Comment: The OP posted *non-working code*.  That doesn't belong on CR.  CR is to critique *working* code.  The fact that most people don't understand the scope of other sites is exactly why you *don't* have a migration path there.  The fact that that question doesn't describe the problem at all means that it likely should be closed on SO to, but if edited, SO is likely where it would be on topic.

Comment: I understand how saying `I it outputting what I want it to output, but I KNOW there is an easier way to do what I do` makes it look like it's working code, but it's not really. He basically has it working in the sense that a series of static print statements would work. The actual question is "how do I use a for loop and function at all"

Comment: @DavidRobinson CodeReview101? ;-)

Comment: @assylias ...more like Programming 101.

Comment: @assylias I don't see it as a Code Review question of any form. An analogy would be "I want to calculate the population of the United States based on demographic data. My best solution now is `print "313.9 million"`. How can I improve my code?"

Comment: I'll be honest, I used to want this.  I used to want this *badly*.  And then I started looking at the types of questions that people wanted to move to codereview.  They're **bad**.  They're mostly just bad.  I'm not convinced that a voting body can be trusted at all with a migration button, as it creates these "us vs. them" politics where one group dumps a bunch of low-quality questions on another group and feelbads ensue.

Comment: @Servy: Precisely.  We're still getting many off-topic questions from SO due to users telling the OP to move their question to CR.  If this keeps up, then SO may not become a migration path *even after graduation*.

Comment: Related: [Redirection to Code Review](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253975/456814).

Comment: @Jamal From the moment I first heard of CR I was reasonably confident that there would never be a migration path, even after it leaves beta.

Comment: I admit that I greatly want this - I've seen a lot of posts with code dumps that just ask 'how can I write this better?' To me, that's asking for a code review. I don't care if the code works or not, I haven't run it to see - if they are asking for improvement, that's asking for a review.

Answer (score 19):

##[From Code Review Meta Site](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1689/31503)

## Checklist for migration to Code Review

1. Is the question calling for a code review?

- The author of the question must be an author or maintainer of the code.
- Requests to explain others' code are off-topic.
- In Code Review, answers may cover any aspect of the code, including
  the algorithm, data structures, code organization, naming, and style.
  (The code in the question must be preserved as the author intended —
  including whitespace.)

2. Is the question off-topic on the originating site?

- Are you sure? Do not migrate if there is doubt.

3. Is the question [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for Code Review?

- The question must contain **working code**.  Code Review is *not* a
  debugging service.  Reviewers *may* discover bugs in the course of
  answering, but the code should be generally correct in the first place.
- If the code is hosted externally, the code that lies at the heart of the
  question must still be written directly in the question itself.
- Code excerpts are fine, but they must be recognizable as code that would
  appear in a real project.  Hypothetical code (such as code that uses `foo` as an identifier), stub code (with unimplemented placeholders in places central to the question), or pseudocode (not in a real programming language)
  are not suitable for Code Review.

4. If there are answers already, they must be good answers on Code Review too.

- Good Code Review answers explain how to improve the code.
- Answers that just contain code with no explanation are not allowed.
- If the answer proposes a completely different solution, there should also
  be a mention of why the approach is superior to the original code.

5. Has the question already been asked on Code Review?

- Please check for duplicate questions from the same author.

If you are unsure whether a question is a good candidate for migration to
Code Review, feel free to ask for an opinion in our
[chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor).

---

#[Discussion And Further Reading:](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1688/31503)

*(the bulk of this answer is <strike>plagiarized</strike> borrowed from: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/241497) - I have taken that and adapted it to focus on Code Review specific concerns)*

#Migrating *to* Code Review:

1. Background
2. General Constraints
3. Technical Constraints
4. Question Constraints
5. Answer Constraints

---

#Background

Migration allows a question that is off-topic on one site in the Stack Exchange network to Code Review (where it will be on-topic) gracefully. It preserves the current revision of the question, all its answers, and any comments on any of those posts, as well as most of the votes.

###What alternatives to Migration are there

Just because a question can be migrated, does not mean that it should. If in doubt, vote-to-close the question (it is off-topic), and add a comment suggesting the asker should read the [on-topic help for Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and that they may want to re-ask their question there.

This is a perfectly fine alternative to migration, and in many cases it is better.

###Side Effects of Migration:

- **Down votes are cleared** from the question upon its migration.
- If a user who has participated in the question does not have an account on the target site, their username is displayed as plain-text until they create an account there.
- **Answers on the origin site are deleted immediately** upon question migration (this causes a reversal of all associated reputation on the origin site).
- **The question is left as a stub**, or pathway to the new site, **for 30 days**, after which it is automatically deleted (again, this causes a reversal of all associated reputation on the origin site).

###Process for a 'bad' migration

A question can rejected by the target community after it has already been migrated if it gets closed as a reason other than duplicate, or gets deleted (usually by the owner) on the target site. When a question which was already migrated gets rejected, the entire process of the migration is reversed. All the answers are returned to the origin site and undeleted (unless the question was deleted on the source site) and are subsequently deleted on the target site.

---

#General Constraints

- [**Don't Migrate Crap**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82986/241497)
- [When in doubt, don't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32474/241497)
- The asker of the Question that is to be migrated may not want it moved

---

#Technical Constraints

#### Code Review is a Beta Site

Questions posted on graduated sites can be *automatically* migrated to some of the other sites by users with close-voting privileges. If enough users vote-to-migrate, the migration will just happen.

*But*... Code Review is a Beta site and as a consequence it is not available as an automatic migration path.

The right way to start the migration process of a question to Code Review is to flag the question 'for Moderator Attention' and as part of the custom message, indicate:

> *This question may be a candidate for migration to Code Review*

***Code Review requires manual/coordinated intervention from moderators on the source site, and often from Code Review as well***

##Older Questions

Only questions which are younger than 60 days can be migrated to other sites. This rule applies even to moderators on the site.

---

#Question Constraints

#### Off-topic on source site

It goes without saying that there is no point in migrating a question that is on-topic where it is. This sounds silly, but it is possible for questions to be on-topic on multiple sites. Although a question would be great on Code Review, it may also be good-enough on its current site.

#### On-topic on Code Review

The question should be on-topic on Code Review. This should be obvious, but the standard for on-topicness should be even higher for migrated questions. It should be a 'reference quality' question. If there is any doubt about this, **don't**!

#### Duplicate on Code Review

Has the question already been asked here?

---

#Answer Constraints

If the question already has answers on the source site, then migration is probably not a good solution:

**Avoid migrating answered questions.** The point of migration is to send the question to an on-topic place when it *can* get answered. If the OP already has an answer, then we've already defeated the purpose of migration and the destination site won't have anything to do with the question. Avoid migrating these questions unless they are of extremely good quality and risk deletion on the current site.

If there are answers, *they would all need to be good answers on Code Review too*.

Answer (score 8):

The general rule with migrations is that a beta site cannot be a migration path.  This is mainly because that site may not be around for good, so it'll just be taken off the list.

Regarding Code Review, I don't think this is a good idea as we're still getting many off-topic posts due to these recommendations.

Here's the usual procedure:

1. A new user posts an off-topic question.
2. Someone checks their SO profile for the same question.
3. If found, that person corrects the user who recommended cross-posting.

This is not what we should be doing.  It gets tiring, and it makes us trust SO less and less.  It's mainly due to users recommending another site *before* reading their Help Center.  Even worse, this is done by some high-rep users who should (ideally) know to read up on a site's Help Center.

What can we do?  At this point, we just have to keep correcting these SO users.  I suspect they're not the usual MSO users, so they may never read any of these posts.  They can, of course, *read the question carefully* first.  If they do recommend CR, then at least we can say that they tried to determine where the question belongs.  Unfortunately, some users in the past have been *way off*, implying that they have *not* read the question in its entirety.