# 'Try Code Review' flag

Tags: discussion, flags, migration, code-review-se

There are several flagging options akin to the following:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>   for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>   for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

I frequently see new users ask questions that would fare well on Code Review, but really have no place on SO. Such questions get flagged and closed quickly with ill-fitting justification, and I worry that this might deter the new users from joining Stack Exchange in a more permanent capacity... the questions are often well constructed despite being off topic here. Have we considered plans to implement a similar flag option for Code Review if/when it finishes its beta?

Comment: Related: [Can we move questions from Stack Overflow to CodeReview.SE?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254080/1305253)

Comment: Note the close flagger: the other post is *related*, but this post asks a very different question. It is *not* a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters - I was just about to comment to that effect, but you've beat me to it. As usual.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Yes, Code Review is likely to be a migration target (*belongs on another site* ->) *when it comes out of Beta*; Tim Post (community manager) [has already stated this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191347/can-we-add-code-review-to-the-migration-list):

> However, I'll go out on a limb and say that we'll *very likely* set this up once Code Review is set to graduate, possibly even before the design and such are ready. Of all the migration paths on the network, this is definitely one of the more obviously good ones.

Manual (moderator-handled) migrations have been very successful so far, with 87 migrations and only 9% rejected in the past 90 days. This is on par with Cross Validated and Super User migrations, and only DBA saw more migrations. However, Beta sites cannot ever be part of that list, so we'll have to wait until that point.

Comment: we are patiently waiting over here at Code Review....

Comment: It could be a likely migration path, *if* the SO community learns what CR really expects.  While our migrations are good (an SO mod as to initiate it), cross-posting recommendations in comments are the problem.  Although migrations require multiple votes from the community, there's still a chance of all of them voting to migrate a bad question to CR.  This has been a problem for a while, and there are some existing answers that address this.

Comment: @Jamal: every migration target has to deal with this, of course. With education (keep the correcting comments coming!) we can get there.

Comment: * With 87 migrations (but probably closer to 300 flags for migration that got declined). I'd be interested to see how high the rejection rate would sore if this site got added as a migration path.

Comment: I know, but as most migrations come from SO, it's up to the community to learn.  Ultimately, it's up to the CMs to decide if CR should be a migration path.  They have the data.

Comment: Good points, all. Not sure how I missed that post on Meta SE, but I appreciate the link!

Comment: @animuson: a smaller number of people can actually vote to migrate (as opposed to flag), and it'll take a consensus of at least 3 such votes to actually make the migration. How many of those 300 rejected flags were from people flagging the same question?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Migration from SO requires [at least 4 migration votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/). It's 3 on other sites.

Comment: code review is out of beta, can this be implemented now?

Comment: I frequently run across SO questions that should be migrated to CR.  So yes, please please please implement this now!

Comment: @RemyLebeau The idea has been shot down due to the amount of low-quality questions which would be migrated to CR. CR simply doesn't have the manpower to handle that influx. There have been a couple of meta's about it, [including this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311348/1014587).