# What is the latest on adding Code Review to Off-Topic Migration Options?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, migration, code-review-se

It's been a year since this was discussed [Add Code Review to 'belongs on another site' now that the site has graduated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276017/add-code-review-to-belongs-on-another-site-now-that-the-site-has-graduated)

What is the latest progress with this?

Comment: I'm reluctant to consider it right now since there doesn't seem to be a lot of questions that are eligible for migration; they'd reject crap and we don't want to migrate crap either.

Comment: IIRC, the CR community has a final say in this. They said no.

Comment: Where'd they say that, @Mast?  That's actually an answer you've got there.

Comment: We are still seeing many times each day on Code Review some _really bad_ questions getting suggested to post to CR instead. I seriously don't think enough people on Stack Overflow understand what is on-topic on Code Review yet for it to be an advantageous migration path.

Comment: from the [previous meta post:](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276038/1803692) "About 10 to 20 questions per day are suggested as migration candidates to Code Review through the comments: SEDE Query - Code Review Recommendations. Only about 1 question per day is actually migrated. Either the other questions are not flagged, or they are cross posted, or the flags are declined."

Comment: @Phrancis:  That's exactly my reluctance.  Even I've screwed that up once or twice, and I should know better.  Just because a question claims to be about review doesn't mean it's a *good* review question...

Comment: @Phrancis fair enough. Yes there's no point using it as a dump site for SO rubbish, and if there is the propensity for that to happen, then yes, it is better not.

Comment: @MrsEd [See this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Code+Review&user=125580&room=8595)

Comment: I'm wondering if it's an idea to ask for a feature request and have it rejected, so the issue is closed, at least for a while?

Comment: I suppose the inverse of this would be, why do you feel that Stack Overflow *needs* a migration path to Code Review?  What exemplary questions are you seeing that would be suitable and on-topic over there?

Comment: @Makoto Made it an answer, for some value of 'answer'.

Comment: @Phrancis thanks for that, I bookmarked the CR meta question linked in the chat. it's good.

Comment: @Makoto true, true.. I've noticed that this question comes up a bit, so might be good to have a definitive answer, now it appears there is one.

Comment: My opinion is that I am willing to give it a try, and evaluate it after a month. Maybe then we could finally say: "OK, this won't work." or we notice "Alright, maybe it can work out". But the scope of Code Review is one of Stack Exchange's more complicated ones, I believe.

Comment: @SimonForsberg:  If you're prepared for it, then more power to you.  Here's hoping that the inevitable Meta discussion about it goes well.

Comment: @SimonForsberg well I'll leave this question unanswered if that's an option.

Comment: @MrsEd Yes, it is fine to leave this unanswered for right now.

Answer (score 20):

TL;DR:

## Not happening.

Not yet, anyways.

---

## Why not?

Well, for one, we are seeing many times each day some **[really bad questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Code+Review&user=125580&room=8595)** getting suggested to post to Code Review instead.

I seriously don't think enough people on Stack Overflow understand (yet) what is on-topic for Code Review. At the current time it would not be an advantageous migration path, but rather it would result in (more) frustrated users who now have **two bad questions** instead of just one.

> Now they have two problems.

---

## OK, so what now?

So you are on Stack Overflow and looking at a question, and you notice it *might* be better suited for Code Review. What can you do?

It turns out, this has been a hot topic on Code Review for quite some time.
So, what *you* can do, as a Stack Overflow contributor:

1. Read this: **[A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)**
2. Read this: **["3 questions" in Stack Overflow comments pointing to Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5468/3-questions-in-so-comments-pointing-to-cr)**
3. If you think the post you are considering is actually on-topic for Code Review, **make a comment about it**.

Trust me, we (Code Review regulars) will respond accordingly and confirm to the best of our ability whether or not it is on-topic for Code Review.

Answer (score 19):

Because the Code Review community hasn't agreed they'd accept one yet.

Is that relevant? Yes. Let me quote Pops, who mentioned after a migration from Code Review to Stack Overflow was set-up:

> FYI: this migration path only goes one way, from CR to SO; it doesn't let questions come from SO to CR. That surely would require more community discussion.

[(source)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/why-wasnt-the-community-consulted-before-adding-stack-overflow-as-a-migration-t#comment13910_6144)

This could change over time, or it could not. Many migration suggestions to Code Review are rejected and a path would increase the amount of possible migrations.

Answer (score 11):

A migration path may eventually happen, someday.  But first, we need Stack Overflow users to fully understand what is on-topic for Stack Overflow and what is off-topic for Code Review, so that inappropriate migrations don't occur.

Here is [a proposal](/q/313266/1157100) for clarifying the Help Center page and standardizing an off-topic reason to be applied to code review requests.

Comment: This is very interesting. I don't understand why this had a downvote.

Comment: I don't think this notion is correct. Users will never know what Code Review is about until we start sending them there. Ultimately this should be the job of a network-wide question wizard, though.

Answer (score 9):

A **very** important reason why we're **very** wary of allowing a SO --> CR migration path:

> SO gets 7,900 questions/day
>   CR gets .....37

If even 1% of SO questions were incorrectly migrated to CR, our site would become 2/3 crud overnight.

Even at present, where the only people who can suggest CR are those who already know it exists, a staggeringly high percentage of recommendations are completely inappropriate.

Imagine how much worse it would be if it was opened up to the SO population at large?

(Stats as of 28 July 2016)

Comment: *"If even 1% of SO questions were incorrectly migrated"* - why did you choose 1% and not 50%? Though my statistic might be around 1% (say 1 post out of 100), but  it's not "incorrectly migrated" one. I am quite confident in my choice if someone posted a complete method with question like "how can I improve that mess", less confident if it's about architecture. It's quite thrilling to hear about "SO population" being called "garbage" here and there, but [close-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) is filtering the worst. Are those garbage-people too?

Comment: The fact is that CR get so little posts it because SO gets most of them. 99% of them to be more precise (same precision as your numbers). And there is not "comfortable" way for SO users to deal with it because of statements like in your answer.

Comment: My point was that what might be a perfectly good question for SO can be completely inappropriate for CR. And (at least when I wrote that 2 years), a high % of SO->CR migrations are either rejected or insta-closed on CR for being Off-Topic for that site. So we'd prefer not to encourage more SO migration volume.