# Code review Off Topic

Tags: discussion, support, questions, flags, code-review-se

I've read in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272109/6583901) that the Code Review site is going to be a migration target as soon as the site comes out of Beta. What should be done with questions suited for the Code Review site until the end of the Beta phase?

- Flag as Blatantly off-topic and leave a comment that the person should go to Code Review
- Just leave a comment that he might get better answers on Code Review
- Do nothing?
- Something else?

Comment: related generic discussion about migration on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285467/a-proposed-philosophy-of-question-migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've read in this post that the Code Review site is going to be a migration target as soon as the site comes out of Beta.

It didn't make it up to be a stock migration site beyond coming out of Beta state.

You can flag code review requests as being *off-topic* as *too broad* and put an advisory comment that the question fits better for [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), as long the code in question is working.

(The latter constraint may be one of the reasons why it's not presented as a migration choice)

Comment: shouldn't this also contain the precautions like *don't migrate crap* and *be 100% sure the question is on-topic at the target* and *when in doubt don't migrate, consult meta*?

Comment: @rene does it make sense to ask on meta about every specific question one is not a 100% sure about?

Comment: @rene Sure! Have some NPK!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry to ask but what is `PHK`?

Comment: @Dr.Fre does it make sense to give users of an rejected migration a shitty experience? There is somewhere a balance I guess?

Comment: @rene _@Dr._ NPK of course. Basic plant nutrition.

Comment: I hate inside jokes ...

Comment: @rene We hate humor at all? Isn't that what makes us _serious_, _professional_ and _expert_?

Comment: @Dr.Fre There's always something to learn from sibling science slots.

Comment: @Dr.Fre Stack Overflowians are inherently good at migrating stuff that shouldn't be migrated. Hence, no one wants to be on our stock migration target list.