# Where should "could someone please explain this code to me" questions go?

Tags: discussion

I just stumbled upon this question

[Requesting insight on ruby code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206497/requesting-insight-on-ruby-code)

where the OP asks whether someone could explain certain pieces of Ruby code to him.

My gut feeling tells me that this is off-topic on SO, so I'd vote for closing and migration, but according to [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers), it is OT on CodeReview, as well.

So, where is this question supposed to go to? Software Engineering?

Comment: No, it is off-topic on Software Engineering. Even better, it is **not** off-topic here on Stack Overflow, why migrate it away at all? It may have other quality issues, perhaps, in which case you can downvote or close. Migration is not needed.

Comment: If they just dump code and say, "I don't understand this code. Please explain it." then it should be closed. But, here, where they have shown that they have put effort into the trying to understand as here "Does that imply defining a class with the module name?", then I think it belongs here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of these questions *tend* to be too broad, and should be closed accordingly.  If, however, the question is specific enough that it's not just asking to "explain everything" but it in fact specifies a question about the code that is narrow enough to answer, then (barring any other problems, such as being unclear) the question is fine and should stay where it is.

There isn't any other site that is any more appropriate than SO.

Comment: It should be noted that there is however an Area 51 proposal named exactly [Code Understanding](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65174/code-understanding)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I'd be pretty shocked to see it become a real site, given the state of the proposal as it is now.  It appears to be doing nothing to address the problems discussed here, namely just a dump of code with a "Please explain" is way too broad; there's no way of knowing what isn't understood about the code and trying to explain *everything* is simply not possible, as even the simplest programs generally have tons of complexity.  For the site to go further that community is going to need to do a lot to address these problems.

Comment: Proposal was removed from A51. Oh well