# "How does this code works" questions

Tags: discussion, questions

Recently I saw a code asking about how does the specific line of code works and there was a discussion that "questions seeking for debugging help aren't allowed here and we are not code-explanation site". So are those questions allowed for StackOverflow or is there another site that is more adequate for this?

Comment: Relevant: [How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions) and [Where should “could someone please explain this code to me” questions go? \[duplicate\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260466/where-should-could-someone-please-explain-this-code-to-me-questions-go)

Comment: Those questions are dangerously broad, and probably off topic on any SE site.  There may be other random sites though.

Comment: FWIW, *questions seeking for debugging help aren't allowed here* isn't true. You can ask for debugging help but you *"...must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**."*

Comment: @BSMP Yeah, I know. But i feel those questions aren't seeking for debugging help. As others stated, they should be marked as Too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are not a code explanation site. So asking

> How does this line of code works?

would probably get down voted for lack of research (there is for sure documentation somewhere that explains what that code does, or at least some part of it) and close voted for being too broad or unclear.

You can ask that question if you share the documentation that you found, explain what you expect it to do based on the docs and then show the outcome of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows a different outcome. That unexpected behavior is a reason to ask:

> How does this line of code works?