# Migration of code questions from Stack Overflow to Code Review

Tags: feature-request, migration, code-review-se

Why is there not an option to close a post on Stack Overflow and migrate it to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)?

I can move it to other Stack Exchange sites, but only 5-6 of them. Is it because Code Review is a beta site?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There are <s>three</s> two primary reasons why Code Review is not on the migration list:

1. <s>It's still in beta and beta sites don't appear on migration lists.</s>
2. There's a limit of 5 migration targets and one of those has to be the site's meta. To occupy the fourth slot there has to be a history of good migrations to that site.
3. I'm not sure that the average user with the close vote privilege would know what a **good** Code Review question looked like - I know I'm not certain. Ideally you'd want to restrict the ability choose this option to people who had significant reputation on Code Review (but that's not going to happen).

In the mean time if you find a **good** question that's not [on topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) that would [make a good Code Review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) use the *"other (needs ♦ moderator attention)"* flag option to request a migration:

[image: screenshot of flag modal panel with "other" option highlighted]

Include a reason why you believe the migration would be useful. We'll get round to it and if we agree we'll migrate.

Comment: There is no longer an "other - Needs Moderator attention" that I can find. What is the recommended mechanism now? "off topic because ..." - "other ..."?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - there should be. It's the last option on the dialog you get when you click the "flag" link.

Comment: Ah! I was going through the "close question" route - my bad. Thanks for clarifying. Will try that next time.

Comment: How about now that CodeReview is out of beta? Are SU, TeX, DBA, and Stats all used more than CodeReview would be?

Comment: By "_I know I'm not certain_" did you mean to say "_I know I certainly would not_"?

Comment: Apparently,  these additional rules apply for custom flags: [Questions should not be migrated away unless they are clearly (1) off-topic for the site where they were originally asked, (2) on-topic for the proposed target site, (3) of notably high quality.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/420563). The last rule would almost surely make the flag prone to be declined for most questions.

Answer (score 25):

A common problem for Code Review is that many Stack Overflow users refer the wrong questions to Code Review.

Also see [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)

To sum it up, Code Review gets way too many questions in the form of *"My code does not do xyz as it should, what is wrong?"*. These questions do not belong on Code Review, so then someone on Code Review checks the following:

- Does the OP have a Stack Overflow account?
- Has the OP posted the same or a very similar question on SO?
- Was there a comment suggesting the OP to go to Code Review?

Way too often the answer to all these three questions are yes, which makes us add comments telling the person who added the comment that it was an incorrect suggestion.

This makes it unlikely that Code Review becomes a migration target for Stack Overflow even after Code Review is out of beta.

Comment: That's true, but I've seen a host of questions of the type "Is this the way I'm meant to do X?" or "I have done this and a co-worker has done that, which is best?" type thing which I think would be appropriate for migration.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald Then you have some options: 1) Vote to close as too broad / primarily opinion based. 2) Add a comment informing the OP about Code Review and mentioning that it *might* be on-topic there. 3) Flag for migration (using the "Other" option in the flag menu). Note that these options are not mutually-exclusive.

Comment: I've opted for #2 a couple of times, but would like to be able to move posts which are appropriate in an ideal world.

Comment: @dougajmcdonald As long as many users keep "voting to close because it belongs at Code Review" (which is often done on questions that are not at all off-topic for Stack Overflow), and especially on questions that are not on-topic on Code Review, it's unlikely that Code Review will be a migration target.

Answer (score 7):

The most important reason for not having a migration option to Code Review is that Code Review [doesn't want it](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/what-questions-are-suitable-for-migration-to-code-review-and-how-does-the-proce/1688#1688).

> Code Review has decided to not allow migrations from Stack Overflow (for now?). Therefore, users cannot migrate questions to Code Review just by voting; questions can only be migrated by a moderator of the original site.

We really shouldn't be putting in an option that the target site doesn't want and surely out of politeness that's the first question we should ask if we're suggesting a site be a migration target, i.e. that there's support for that on the target site itself.