# Flag declined for migrating to CodeReview

Tags: discussion, migration, code-review-se

I met [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28153798) yesterday, and vote for close as I think it's more about code review but as there is no option to migrate to Code Review I used [this suggestion:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266750) and it is just a copy of what is written in the current SO's migration vote templates

> Closing >Off Topic>Other>"I'm voting to close this question as
>   off-topic because this belongs on Code Review"

My reason has been converted to a comment (get deleted now), and the question eventually get closed (by moderator as there is only 4 votes) without migration.

Here is the CodeRevie version of [What topics can I ask about here:](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> - Is code included directly in my question? (See Make sure you include    your code in your question below.)
> - Am I an owner or maintainer of the    code?
> - Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or    example code?
> - Do I want the code to be good code? (i.e. not    code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar)
> - To the best of my knowledge,    does the code work as intended?
> - Do I want feedback about any or all    facets of the code?
>
> If you answered "yes" to all the above questions,
>      your question is on-topic for Code Review.

I think the question satisfied every criteria listed, so I flagged it with the question:

> Should this be migrated to CodeReview rather than closed?

It gets declined and here is the answer:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Can anyone tell why this question is not getting migrated as it is on-topic for Code Review?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You did two things on this question:

1. voted to close using the Other reason
2. raised a custom moderator flag to move the question to Code Review

By the time, the custom flag was reviewed by a moderator the question was already closed so the flag was declined. It is very rare that we would reopen a question without any answers to then migrate it another site. Plus, the question raised a ton of comments which to me means that maybe it wasn't in the best shape to be migrated in the first place.

We only will migrate questions that are good quality and on-topic.  I didn't feel that it was a great question that should be reopened and migrated, so I declined your flag. If the OP wants to post it on Code Review, then they could move it themselves.

The events on this post were:

- You voted to close with a custom reason at 2015-01-26 16:21:08, this generated a comment on the question

  > I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review
- There was excessive discussion in the comments which raised a flag at 2015-01-26 16:25:26 for the moderators to review
- A moderator went to the question to review the "too many comments" flag raised above
- the post was closed by the moderator at 2015-01-26 16:56:47
- You then used a custom "Other" flag asking a moderator to step in, reopen, and migrate this post at 2015-01-26 17:18:17 - well after the question was closed.

As I mentioned, we are rarely going to reopen a closed question with no answers to migrate it.  The moderator who closed the question didn't have a flag to move this post to Code Review, your custom close reason is, just that, a vote to close. It is not a vote to migrate, only moderators can migrate to Code Review. When I received your flag asking for it to be migrated, I reviewed the question, etc and declined the flag because, as written, it is not a good question for Code Review.

Comment: As a member on Code Review, thank you very much for not migrating this!

Comment: `By the time, the custom flag was reviewed by a moderator the question was already closed so the flag was declined` but it was closed by another moderator, why shouldn't he/she migrate it instead of closing it, or at least leave a comment tell the user how, as the user was even asking how to do it in the comment(deleted too).

Comment: @Bolu Your custom flag to migrate this to code review was raised after the question was already closed. The question was closed at `2015-01-26 16:56:47` and you raised the flag at `2015-01-26 17:56:41` there was no request to migrate it at that time.  Your close reason posted as a comment, not as a flag to move it. Another mod closed the question because we were drawn to the post by a different flag. Just because there is a comment mentioning Code Review doesn't mean we will migrate it.

Comment: I see, so [this suggestion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266750) is not acceptable cross board. As my reason to close, is to get it migrated to CodeReview...

Comment: Very clear, so am I supposed to just flag for migrating, rather than what I did, if I think it should be migrated to CodeReview (or any other non-listed site)?

Comment: @Bolu If you think a question is on-topic for Code Review, then you would use a custom moderator flag requesting migration.

Comment: [I was misled](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266750) :( Will remember next time..

Comment: So, posts will only ever be migrated by moderators if they are high-quality, on-topic on the target, and already have answers, that sums it up? Must those answers also be good on the target site?

Comment: @Deduplicator Nope that's not what I'm saying. This particular question was already closed **and** no answers on it, why would we reopen a question with no answers to migrate it?  We typically don't. However, if a question has been flagged for migration, it's been closed, it's on-topic for the target site, good quality, **and** it has answers, then there _may be_ a case to migrate it.  But it would happen on a case by case basis when the moderator reviewed the flag, it is not cut and dry.

Comment: @Bolu - note that in ChrisF's answer you were 'misled' by, the 'other' means other ***flag***, not other close reason. I have edited ChrisF's post to be more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

The question does not have any answers that need to be migrated along with it, so there's no reason a moderator needs to step in and migrate it. The OP can just delete the question on SO and repost it on Code Review. This is the process that should normally be followed so that people are encouraged to go look on the appropriate site before reposting, instead of just having a possible duplicate question whisked away for them by a moderator.

Comment: Alright, I have left a comment there.

Comment: Sounds similar to an answer I made on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215148/shall-migration-be-further-tuned-in-the-sense-of-moderation-theory/215155#215155 - that way, no deleted questions, and new posts, and everyone *should* be better off... I think :)

Answer (score 1):

You voted to close the question, but you didn't vote to migrated it.  It is therefore unsurprising that the question was closed without being migrated.

The fact that you used a custom reason saying that the question belongs on CR doesn't mean that the question will be migrated if is't closed for that reason.

I'd also like to take a moment to point out that the reason you gave for closing the question is not a valid reason for closing a question.  A question being on topic on another site doesn't automatically make it off topic on SO.  And even if it *is* offtopic on SO; you should be explaining why it *doesn't* belong on SO, not where else it is on topic (or both, I guess, if you want).  If the question doesn't belong on SO because it is too broad, not clear, subjective, etc. then say *that* when closing it.  If you want to direct the user to another site where the question might be on topic, you can do that *in addition* to explaining why its not on topic here.

Comment: Hi there is no option to migrate to Code Review, and I was using [this suggested approche](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266750)

Comment: @Bolu You are correct; there is no option for you to vote to migrate a question to CR.  It is therefore all the more unsurprising that when you voted to close the question, it wasn't migrated to CR.