# Why can't I flag a question to be migrated to codereview.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, flags, migration

I sometimes encounter questions on SO that are better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com. However when I try to flag such a question for migration, I get a very short list of irrelevant options to migrate to. Why is that?

For instance, I wanted to flag this question for migration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258739/php-pdo-mysql-insert-function

Here is the list of options:

[image: migration options]

Comment: As well as that: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266749/migration-of-code-questions-from-stackoverflow-to-codereview

Comment: Oops, sorry, was too quick to ask, not thorough enough to google. Too reliant on suggestions showing nothing similar.