# Should the Triage Review tab have the option of shifting the question to another site?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, triage, site-recommendation

I have recently come across a question in the Triage review page:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18361937

This question is best fit for the code review site. My reputation is currently a bit lower than 3k but I think there is no button to directly take a question to another site on the triage page. You need to go to the question page and then shift it to another site.

I think this would be a much loved feature to have for the triage review page.

Just pasting the original question here:
[Python, given a word, generate a list with one letter changing for each letter in alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991503/python-given-a-word-generate-a-list-with-one-letter-changing-for-each-letter-i)

**EDIT**

I am not asking for specifically a direct migration path here. But we do need a way to flag the question then and there in the review page. I mean, some part of the triage review has to result in flags invariably. So why not have the option to flag the question then and there?

Comment: Maybe not for Triage, but would be good for other queues to [have the "other" option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187824/364344).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Triage review queue doesn't have this option because it's not a dedicated migration path on Stack Overflow. [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/4751173) shows the reason why that is the case.

It *is* possible to flag a question for migration via Triage, but your options are limited to Meta Stack Overflow (AKA 'here'), Super User, Tex.SE, DBA.SE and Cross Validated:

[image]

For other migrations, you can always choose Unsalvageable -> in need of moderator intervention:

[image]

Comment: Ok, but I think there should be something like flag as off-topic for these situations. Basically I do not want to go to the question page to flag is separately.

Comment: But flagging for migration is just a 'subset' of flagging as off-topic. Because you don't have 3k reputation yet, you can't choose a custom off-topic reason.

Comment: I understand, please read the edit in my question

Comment: You do have the option to flag from the queue, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Ohh! I was really careful about clicking on unsalvagable and hence did not know its use. Thanks a lot for the enlightenment!

Comment: You're welcome. Kudos for being careful and asking here!

Comment: @Glorfindel Thank you