# Was this question really not good enough for migration?

Tags: support, specific-question, flags, declined-flags, migration

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73838257/python-script-for-gregorian-epact) with a custom flag: move to codereview.se. This flag was declined with the reason "Questions should not be migrated away unless they are clearly (1) off-topic for the site where they were originally asked, (2) on-topic for the proposed target site, (3) of notably high quality." I think this question would be on-topic for codereview, because that is a site where people post code and get feedback on it. That's not on-topic here at SO. It's not low-quality. (I think). Why was my flag declined?

Comment: "(3) of notably high quality." -- that question is not of notably high quality. That's NOT the same as saying it's low-quality; quality is not a binary.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine If that's the case,  maybe the reason could be more clear. The `,` maybe interpreted as `OR`(if any of these 3 rules apply) or `AND`(all of these should apply).  Adding a conjunction would help clarity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure the folks over at Code Review would appreciate the question.

I often close vote on non-English questions which (I assume) could definitely fit in the relevant language-specific SO. However, I vote to close them as "Needs details or clarity", rather than a custom flag to have them moved, and I often leave a comment for the asker telling them to either ask in English, or go to the whichever language-specific SO.

However, as I'm not fluent in any of those languages, and not familiar with the specific SO sites, I leave it to the asker to check that their question is in line with the guidance.

We shouldn't really be custom-flagging questions to have them moved to another site unless there's a really compelling reason.