# Unclear redirections

Tags: discussion, code-review-se

Today I had a question about some code I wrote.

My question was put on hold and I was told to go to codereview, because the code was complete. (it was complete but I tried to shorten it, which didn't work for me at first)

But the folks over there told me that the question was off-topic, because it wasn't about code reviewing, but about my 'unfinished' code.

What should I do in such a situation?

Comment: Is your code complete and working, or is it incomplete and not actually working?

Comment: You should put a [link to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925820/how-could-i-simplify-this) for clarification.

Comment: related: [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually I believe it is this deleted one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944438/shorten-this-code-with-switch (10k only)

Comment: Take the recommendations of others to go visit another site with a grain of salt. Always read through the site's help center before posting to make sure that what you want to ask is on-topic. If users aren't reasonably active on a target site, they really shouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: Can't see the SO question, but I think @bluefeet is correct.  The [question over on CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77502/shorten-this-code-using-switch) is definitely not the undeleted on-hold question on SO.

Comment: I think Code Review has become the new dumping ground that Programmers used to be

Comment: It was incomplete and not fully functional @Servy

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I couldn't find it...

Comment: @bluefeet correct

Comment: Probably @LittleBobbyTables

Comment: @RobinvanderNoord If the code was incomplete and not working, then you should have explained that to whomever was telling you that your code was complete and fully functional, or edited the question to make it clearer in what way the code is not working.

Comment: @Servy Okay thank you. The question was put on hold by 4/5 people...

Comment: @RobinvanderNoord Yes, because apparently the question that you were asking is radically different than what you actually wanted out of an answer.  You just dumped some code and said "simplify".  You didn't explain what wasn't working, specifically, or even give any indication that anything about it wasn't working.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables luckily not nearly in that amount as it was (and somewhat still is the case) with programmers. There's been some discussions around this on all involved metas ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your [now deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944438/shorten-this-code-with-switch) basically a large block of code. And you stated "I want to rewrite it to use a `switch`.  I've written something..."

> But that doesn't seem to work that well...

The last line of your question is the key.  You don't have working code.

Yes, someone commented to you suggesting Code Review but the exact comment is:

> If this is working code you might want to post to Code Review instead.

You don't have working code, so you shouldn't have posted the question to Code Review.  Code Review has very specific [requirements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers) for questions on the site. From that linked question:

> In a nutshell:
>
> - Real code has to be written.
> - The code has to work.
> - Broken code or troubleshoot bugs is off-topic.
> - Requests to explain others' code are off-topic.

When another user makes a suggestion for another site, that doesn't mean copy and paste the question to it.  Read what is on-topic before posting a question to make sure your question fits into the guidelines.

Now for your question on SO, it was put on hold as "unclear what you are asking."  Before deleting and moving it, you could try to make this on-topic for SO.  Shorten the question to include your switch and explain "why it doesn't work well".  Make some improvements to the question, here, to try and make it on-topic for the site.

Comment: That someone who posted the comment about Code Review might also want to consider taking a few extra seconds scanning through the question to see if there is any indication that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

## Ask the same question

A common thing we on Code Review encounter is that on Stack Overflow, a question is asked about how to improve the code. But once the question appears on Code Review, **the question is different** and it is indicated that the code does not do what it is supposed to do.

This leads to trouble for all of us. So when being recommended to ask your question on a different site, remember that that is for the current state of your question. If you change your question, it might also change where it is on-topic.

Also remember that some users, when recommending another site, might not be correct. We on Code Review continuously educate Stack Overflow users whenever we encounter an incorrect suggestion to post on CR.

It is also helpful for Code Review if you include a link to your Stack Overflow question, so that we can see whether or not you asked about the same thing in both questions.