# I think this may be off-topic problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons, custom-close-reasons

Recently (today maybe) has changed the [predefined comment for *Other* reason when closing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1OAF.png) a question as *Off-Topic* from:

> This question appears to be off-topic because `<place for the reason>`

to

> I think this may be off-topic because `<place for the reason>`

I'm not a native English speaker, but it doesn't sound much descriptive to me. What is **this** in that context? It may well be mistaken e.g. with a reaction to a preceding comment:

> User 1: Does your code ever exit the loop?
>   User 2: I think this may be off-topic because this question is about homing pigeons.

Did the User 2 say to the User 1 that their comment is off-topic or not? Could we refer the question again, e.g.:

> I think **this question** may be off-topic because `<place for the reason>`

?

Comment: Being a native English speaker, I wouldn't know you weren't a native English speaker if you hadn't pointed it out...spot on. Weird change. Possibly just an oversight somewhere.

Comment: @GrantWinney Probably... but this kind of shenanigan with language just makes me want to replace the text with "This question is off topic because..."

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it is more suitable for http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's not broken, let's break it! Why even make such pointless changes that add nothing to the site? I think this SO dev team has too little to do...

Comment: @Lundin, the close reasons are defined per site and are [managed by diamond moderators](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184637).

Comment: @TLama Maybe it shouldn't be managed by them, then...

Comment: @Louis I did in fact usually replace the predefined comment with "This question _is_ off topic because [...]". I already think "appears to be" is way too defensive - most questions where I use this reason are so clearly off topic that any other wording makes no sense; e.g. questions about licensing or similar legal issues. I have no idea why anybody would change this to something even more defensive. With the current text I would probably delete the beginning and simply write "off topic because [...]".

Comment: codeMagic: I think we know the OP is not a native English speaker because he or she wrote "much descriptive" instead of "very descriptive".

Comment: This meta question would be better on meta.se, not meta.so. It is a network-wide change.

Comment: @TLama - as a mod on another site, I *know* it's not a custom close reason, and it is affecting all SE sites, not just SO.

Comment: @rolfl, thanks! Well, then be so. I thought they were custom ones.

Comment: Note that the site-specific close reasons are editable by site-moderatorrs, but this is the 'other' reason which is not moderator controlled, but part of the code base.

Comment: @rolfl, I see, but I would expect them to write even that *template* for *other* reason (or inherit from SE if empty e.g.). I would implement it that way, personally.

Comment: That's not the way it currently works, @TLama - but it may be a decent [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: Possibly relevant discussion on [Math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/19332/23353).  This isn't a custom close reason, as rolfl pointed out.

Comment: @rolfl It's ok to post bugs and feature requests on a per-site meta, even about network-wide features. [Don't make Recebba Chernoff cry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89228/which-meta-am-i-supposed-to-post-on/89232#89232)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh hey, good point. That did end up being accidentally more confusing than we intended.

> I think this question may be off-topic because `<place for the reason>`

will be live next time we build out.

Comment: Far too defensive, as others pointerd out. But at least no longer potentially confusing.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah, whether or not the change is a good idea in the first place is a separate argument. I personally don't have an opinion on it at this point, but I wanted to take the confusion out of the equation here.

Comment: Well, where do we complain to make it not defensive then?

Comment: "That did end up being accidentally more confusing than we intended." - Well, what did you intend? Why change it at all? Seems like a clear case of "it's not broken, let's break it".

Comment: @bjb568 You know how meta works. A discussion post would be suitable.

Comment: @l4mpi We intended the new version not to be confusing, obviously. I don't know the reasons behind the change. Someone from the community team would have to comment on that.

Comment: An answer isn't enough? Ok, posted http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284200/2371861

Comment: *"I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because"* finally won. And clearly explains the intention, which was the aim.

Answer (score 102):

> I think this may be off-topic because

I think many things, but what's that have to do with anything? The whole thing uses weak language. "appears to be off-topic" is much better and concrete. Roll back to the old version!

Comment: Even better, change the old version which is already too defensive to "This question _is_ off topic because [...]".

Comment: @l4mpi I disagree about that, see my answer.

Comment: Agreed - it's a weak sentence, which doesn't sound very credible when you're trying to add feedback. By adding "I think" to it, you're making it sound as if the person voting to close isn't even sure themselves whether the question is off-topic, which is definitely not a good thing.

Comment: @AstroCB How about "I consider this question off-topic"?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg That's better, but it still focuses too much on a single person, in my opinion; the point of the comment is to alert the asker that his question is off-topic, and subsequent close votes will be upvotes on that suggestion. I believe the old wording communicates that best.

Comment: @AstroCB in _your_ opinion it focuses too much on a single person, you say?

Answer (score -8):

It takes five users to determine if a question is off-topic. The actual close reason(s) are not shown until the question is actually closed.

It only takes *one* to add this type of comment, and this comment might not be correct or appropriate. There has for example been some issues [when users have recommended Code Review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers). One user is not authoritative. Five users is. Therefore, if one user adds this comment, it should in my opinion not be an authoritative comment.

I agree that it would be better to make the comment like this:

> I think **this question** may be off-topic because `<place for the reason>`

Comment: "If one user adds [it], it should in my opinion not be an authoritative comment." - Comments are _never_ authorative, the only authorative thing is the close banner which appears after the question is closed. Wording the comment template very defensively does not help people who fail to understand that; and we shouldn't optimize for these users anyways. When I use the close reason, it's usually not because I _think_ it _could possibly_ be off topic but _maybe isnt_, or _who knows_ because that changes too often ayways - I am usually _absolutely certain_ that the question _is_ off topic.

Comment: @l4mpi It's good that you're using it that way. However, no matter how you are using it, people are wrong sometimes. That is why I think having a comment like "This question *is* off-topic" as you suggested in your other comment would be a bad idea.

Comment: People are wrong with many more things. Would you also suggest every answer starts with "I think this may possibly be the solution to your problem"? That would be edited out as noise. Or take comments telling people that the code in a post is bad / unsafe / etc (e.g. mysql injections); nobody words these defensively and I don't see any compelling reason why they should. Just because people can be wrong does not mean we should always word everything as defensively as possible - that's why the close reason is a comment, signed with the username, and can be upvoted or disputed by other users.

Comment: Also, again, why would anybody even optimize that for the edge case that the people with >3k rep which we trust with closing questions are wrong? I'd wager they are usually doing ok at not closing good questions, and if they're not then that won't change by changing the wording here. The usual case for this close reason should be a question that is so clearly off topic that none of the default close reasons apply; e.g. legal and licensing issues, support questions etc. Everything else gets closed as unclear/broad these days anyways.

Comment: Even a very low-rep user can type (without actually close-voting) a comment that says the question clearly is absolutely off-topic and as far as I know, there is no way to tell those comments apart.  Actually, I only found out that these comments are added automatically after I've gained close-voting privileges myself.  Before that, I had assumed that this is just a common phrase many users are using.  So I see no point in making those comments as defensive as possible.