# Custom off-topic reasons sound defensive, not concrete

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons, custom-close-reasons

> I think this question may be off-topic because

This is the new custom off-topic reason text. As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283612/2371861), this is weak and defensive. The "I think" part is redundant since the comment is already signed by the user. I propose this:

> This question is off-topic because

It is much stronger and direct. The concrete language will make new users think there is an actual problem that needs to be fixed rather than just a user complaining for no reason.

Comment: This question appears to be getting an upvote from me.  I was going to call the new wording "timid", but "weak and defensive" works just as well.  A majority of the time, there's no "I think" or "It may"... seasoned reviewers **know** an off-topic question when they see one.

Comment: I think this post is getting an upvote from me as well. I've been editing out the new message since I noticed it.

Comment: I think I agree -essentially you're saying: "I think therefore I am ... sounding weak and defensive rather than assertive and correct"

Comment: After carefully pondering the matter and asking a few old men with beards for their sage advice, I think I might probably get behind a motion to get a bit more decisive. Perhaps. I'm still not quite sure though, so please don't try putting any share of the blame for pursuing such a strong position on me.

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because I'm indecisive

Comment: some say opposite, [need moar sugar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247169/increase-close-reasons-from-400-to-512-characters#comment810173_247169). "Dear Sir/Madam user123456789: We are very sorry to inform you that your question has been closed for being too awesome for Stack Exchange to handle. Please accept our sincere apologies for any inconvenience you may have experienced with respect to this. Looking forward to hearing from you. Sincerely yours, [close voters names]"

Comment: ..."IMHO this question may be off-topic because blah blah"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **I like to.**

Answer (score 27):

After some deliberation, I wish to relate how pleased I am to report that I have to say it is my considered opinion that I think your argument may be very close to quite nearly spot-on.

My name is attached to the comment; it's already clearly a statement of my own belief. The new wording is not *that much* fluff, but it's fluff nonetheless, not contributing anything meaningful.

**Much** more importantly, it makes it sound like I'm unsure of my close vote, which is actually **bad**. I should't be casting a vote if I only think something "may be" off topic.

Comment: I think you may be on to something

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that I feel this answer might not, as written, be quite as explicit as I might otherwise have hoped it would be.

Answer (score 26):

**Update:** the boilerplate now reads, "*I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because*". It's not clever, but it is completely accurate.

---

The original goal of *having* comments for "other" was simple: try to expose whatever interpretation of the question was leading to its closure. For blatantly off-topic questions, this doesn't matter much...

- "*prefix* Facebook support"
- "*prefix* child rearing"
- "*prefix* waffles"

...are all fairly redundant, but at least they don't take long to type. For more subtle questions, this can be extremely helpful: if someone suddenly decides that, say, regular expressions or editors are all off-topic and starts leaving a trail of...

- "*prefix* regular expressions" or
- "*prefix* code editors"

...around after them, it becomes clear that there's a problem. It can be discussed and resolved.

In practice, these comments are often not particularly helpful, which something of a perpetual problem *every time the system encourages folks to comment on anything*. But that's a separate issue.

IMHO, we *ought* to be aiming for the tone present in the comments generated for *duplicates*:

> [When one person votes, it's *possibly* a duplicate. When five people vote, it's a duplicate.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70758/wording-of-possible-exact-duplicates-when-closing-the-question/70759#70759)

That doesn't quite work for off-topic though: there's no final stage where it stops being a *possibility* and starts being gospel. The comment is the only record of why the question was closed, and so it has to straddle the line between *possibility* and *actuality*. Hence the original prompt:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about ...

Unfortunately, that led to some awkward situations, which [Robert outlines in his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284200/custom-off-topic-reasons-sound-defensive-not-concrete/284207#284207). I think the motivation for changing this was solid, especially since these comments often hang around on questions that *don't* get closed, leading casual readers to make incorrect assumptions ("I saw someone say that editors were off-topic here - we need a separate site for Vim!").

Getting away from the passive, semi-authoritative tone is good, but if it tips so far in the "possibility" direction that folks like Bill are re-writing it and Josh is feeling it weakens his opinion, then we haven't hit the right balance either.

- We could just drop the ending:

  > This question appears to be off-topic because ...
- We could more directly attribute the opinion without weakening it:

  > I believe this question is off-topic because ...
- We could straight-up just say what is actually happening:

  > I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ...

Thoughts?

Comment: +1 for "I believe" or "I'm voting to close". They aren't wishy-washy, but it's clearer to people who don't quite get what closing means yet that this isn't an act of a deity, just one user's assessment.

Comment: "I'm voting to close this question" is just *begging* for serial downvote retaliation.

Comment: @bjb568 Close voters are always named when a question is closed.  It's not an anonymous activity, unlike downvoting.  I don't see this making revenge votes any worse than they would be without it.

Comment: +1 for `I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ...`  It has the least possible room for interpretation, and thus the least possibility for *mis*-interpretation.  It's just saying exactly what it means to say; it's not trying to *imply* anything or convey subtleties that people may or may not pick up on.

Comment: @Servy Closed by [list of 5 people] -> Ugh, those nazi moderators, I hate them! I'm voting to close [signed 1 person] -> YOU NAZI MODERATOR SUMMONNNEEEEER! YOU SINGLE HANDEDLY ARE STOPPING MY QUESTION AND MY CAREER! Basically, it's a lot easier to focus when there's one person (with power) who looks like they're expressing their own opinion vs it's already closed and it's really all of the 5 people's faults and not a single one of theirs.

Comment: I appreciate this expansion of the staff point of view, but I still don't understand what you and Robert think is "awkward" about his example comment.

Comment: @bjb568 As someone who votes to close a lot of questions, and comments explaining why I'm voting to close questions quite a bit, I just don't see that happening enough to be worried about.  It'll happen every once in a while, but revenge downvoting as a whole is actually far less common then most people think.  I don't see it being worth making the comment more confusing or less descriptive for all of the other cases where there is no revenge voting.

Comment: Fair enough, but even if it isn't a significant effect, if people think it is that may make them reluctant to cast the first custom OT CV.

Comment: Revenge voting is not likely to be an issue here simply because there aren't that many questions that require "other" closure in the first place, and most of them are posted by folks who **can't downvote**. As Servy notes, there's a whole list of names listed *above* the comment, and the occasional idiot who decides to go after them usually just walks down that list. I see *far* more revenge voting from long-time users who are upset over some tone-deaf comment by another long-time user than I do connected to close voting.

Comment: That's why I used different examples, @Josh - hair color isn't on-topic for Stack Overflow, but most folks think regular expressions *are* - so if you're closing a regex question as off-topic, either you have another reason (and should explain it) or you're full of it (and shouldn't appear to be making a statement of fact). Obviously, anyone can claim anything - but the system itself probably shouldn't encourage ridiculous claims.

Comment: If folks go back to using it only for questions that are actually off-topic (and not, say, unclear) that'd be awesome, @bjb568. The number of bone-headed custom OT reasons folks bother to type is staggering - it's like they're using it for catharsis or something.

Comment: All right, I gotcha. I see it entirely the other way around, though: "_Assertive prefix_ variable assignment" is easily debunked and dismissed, whereas "_Waffly prefix_ App Store submission" invites unnecessary debate. (As you say, of course, wherever possible -- and it is possible with "App Store submission" -- it's best to include/link to back up material.)

Comment: Both are easily debunked by you or me, @Josh - my concern is for folks who don't spend a whole lot of time on meta (the Vim example wasn't exactly *hypothetical*).

Comment: I, more often that not, delete the boiler plate prefix, because it's actually quirky to transmit the message I'm trying to convey: what's wrong, why, and how can you fix it. I think that if we remove the boiler plate altogether and put a minimum character restriction (+50?) it could work out. Whenever I see these comments are either nonsensical or downright rubbish, as they don't actually transmit a helpful message (which most close reasons do, why mustn't "other"?).

Comment: While the change does make it a bit less bad, I will still stick to simply deleting the prefix and thus post "off topic because [...]" - I do believe starting the comment with "I'm voting against you" won't exactly be a good idea in many cases. I don't get what you're even trying to do here, or for what case you're supposed to be optimizing - apparently not for the power users who have no problem using custom close reasons correctly. That seems to be a pattern with a lot of things lately...

Comment: That's your prerogative, @l4mpi. Speaking as a "power user", I rarely use this option to begin with and when I do don't much care what it says.

Comment: "I don't much care what it says" is exactly the problem here. It's all about clearly communicating something - the option is usually only used for questions that definitely don't belong on SO, and the message I want to send in this case is _we don't do that topic here_. Not "here's my personal thoughts" or "here's how I voted", simply "OP, this type of question should not be asked on SO". I _do_ care about getting this message across and thus believe in stating it clearly, and without any distractions that make it about my personal actions instead.

Comment: Btw, if I had a diamond next to my name and the ability to close and delete questions by myself, I wouldn't care much about the comment either because my actions would clearly deliver the message. As a non-mod, all I can hope for is teaching op and others who stumble upon ops question that a (type of) question is off topic, and why. Especially in case of questions that are not brand new it's often not easy to get them closed without involving chat etc. Close votes decay but the comment sticks around, which makes it even more important that the comment is clearly worded.

Comment: I was unclear, @l4mpi - sorry. What I meant was, I *very* rarely use "other" except in cases where the question is blatantly off-topic, situations where - as I noted in this answer - the comment is effectively redundant anyway.

Comment: Um, that's kind of what I disputed in my last comment. It's not redundant if the question is *not* quickly closed and deleted. I usually use it for support and legal questions, and if you look at the last batch of questions I voted to close this way, they're still open. I still want to leave the message "SO is not for legal advice", and formulate it in a way that's not about myself or my actions.

Answer (score 5):

We're talking a look at it. Perhaps veering back towards the phrase *"Appears to be…"*  might work better here.

The "more timid" language was really just a secondary aspect of the main change we just implemented — to make that *suggested-comment* a bit more open-ended so users would provide better reasons why they *think* the post should be closed. Too often the previous system would create comments like this:

> [This question appears to be off-topic because it is about...] hair color.

And because of how the feature works, the system automatically posted these personal comments, making them *sound* like someone was quoting gospel.

We're looking at other variations.

Comment: To make the previous version more open-ended, just snip off "it is about", as bjb568 has suggested. It's not really clear from your answer what exactly you don't like about your example comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you want to get users to provide better custom close reasons, don't optimize for the people who use it wrong. Optimize it for the people using it correctly - which means either far out topics (e.g. legal issues, boat programming) or things like support requests and other issues that generally relate to programming but just don't belong on SO. Personally, I edited the comment to "This question is off-topic" even before the change; now I will just delete the prefix and write "off-topic because ...", as I don't want to leave the impression I'm unsure about my close vote.