# Raise Awareness of Automatic Implicit Comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[Brad's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319523/automatic-implicit-comments#comment325395_319523) is the only worded dissent I have read, yet there are many downvotes. If you disagree with me then please explain why?

I am asking that the automatic posting of a comment should be made clear before it happens. To me, downvotes here seem to be saying that those comments should be kept a secret, which is bizarre

This is especially weird as the automatic comment seems to rely either on the amount of text or whether the catalyst text has been left in place

```
I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because
```

I always overwrite this and explain myself in several sentences. I have never seen my reason for closure displayed as a comment, so I can only guess what the criterion may be

This issue was brought to my attention by fellow subscriber [simbabque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331451/simbabque) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36159778/parse-file-using-perl?noredirect=1#comment59959011_36159778) and the subsequent dialogue

It seems that sometimes, and without warning, reporting a post may result in a comment beneath that post containing the ideas and reasons that I assumed were private and for the eyes of the moderators only

This needs to be fixed, either by informing the user clearly that their words will be made public, or by stopping the automated comments

Suppose I want to report a post saying, "My demonstration didn't fail, and she was in bed with me in London while my colleague did it for me, so she didn't even see it"

The specific case that I have encountered recently is when I want to make a *close* vote on the grounds of the post being *off-topic*

I get this prompt

> - off-topic because ...

and more often than not the case isn't covered by the six pre-written choices. (I could submit a question to Stack Overflow about being unable to peel an orange, and it wouldn't be excluded by any of the main options. It's disgraceful.)

So I select the *other* category

> - Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)

and I  get a text box pre-filled with

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because

I tend to use the off-topic/other category to explain myself when none of the other labels seem to fit. In such situations I feel that I should explain myself, and so generally take two or three sentences to phrase my submission, and I have never noticed a situation where my ideas have been published as a comment

I suspect the automation depends either on the length of the text or, more likely, on whether it starts with the stock pre-fill `I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because`

Stack Overflow is full of stuff like this, and it is inappropriate. You can't, and shouldn't try to, automate human ideas and opinions. At the very least, contributors to the site should be made aware that their votes and thoughts will be made public

Comment: Just press CTRL-Home and start to type what you think is the appropriate reason to close the question. It's on your behalf. I would have simply chosen as _unclear what you're asking_ or _too broad_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I can think of many ways to avoid the problem. The issue is that the problem isn't apparent in the first place

Comment: Close Votes are not anonymous, why should your comment be?

Comment: @Borodin, everything about closing is public. The users who vote to close are public. The reason they chose is public. If you choose a custom reason, it is public too.

Comment: @Paulie_D: As far as I know, close votes are made public only if the post is finally closed. Surely I don't need to explain that *reasons* for a vote are much more specific than the vote itself, and the *implication* is that what I type isn't generally accessible. I have no problem with it being so, but in that case the situation should be made clear before the words are submitted

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Given a question with just one downvote, are you saying that there's a place where I can see who placed that vote and their reason?

Comment: When an option explicitly says "(add a comment explaining what is wrong)", what did you think that would do? Where did you think that comment would go?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: *plus ça change, plus c'est la même chose*

Comment: @BradLarson: Enough sarcasm please. The implication is that it will be submitted to the moderators, who will use it to judge whether the post should be closed. It doesn't follow that those words are clear just because you know what really *does* happen

Comment: @Borodin, if you also have the VtC privilege, you can see which reason was chosen (but not by whom). Why are you so afraid of the custom reason being a public comment?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: RIght. However, a comment submitted automatically when I vote to close under *off topic / other* is visible to everyone. This doesn't even make sense: as far as I know no comment is posted automatically for any other class of close request

Comment: @Borodin, yup, that's a special case (quite justified IMHO given you are using a *custom* close reason). That feature is relatively new, it wasn't always like this.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Yes, I'm seeing that. I'm also seeing a startling cluster of downvotes for my request simply to *make it clear* that that *special case* results in an in-line *public* comment, and only sometimes. Quite why that isn't a given I can't imagine

Comment: All I can say is that I think the current wording of "I'm voting to close this" comes off as unnecessarily confrontational and so you don't really expect such a thing to be posted as a public comment. The previous "This question appears to be off-topic because", while a little awkward, was much more passive.

Comment: @BoltClock: I agree with you and would raise that as another issue, but it seems OT for this question. What worries me is the rush to downvote my post when it asks only that the behaviour of the site should be clarified for the *one case* in voting to voting to close when a comment is raised *automatically* and *without warning*. It's looking more and more like the rumours that the site staff are entrenched and defensive are true

Comment: Why the [meta-tag:feature-request] tag?  Do you have a specific feature/change to implement?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: I thought it was clear that I wanted any indirect consequences of actions on the site to be clarified and explained before they were actioned. If I vote for a post to be closed then I expect my vote to be counted and no more. But *uniquely* in the case where I choose `off-topic because...` and then `Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)` my words will be posted as a comment beneath the offending post. There should be a warning that this will happen

Comment: The exact phrasing of the comment [was discussed about a year ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284200/custom-off-topic-reasons-sound-defensive-not-concrete/); the passivity was not found to be a feature, and the template ended up being changed. @BoltClock

Comment: @JoshCaswell: So you're saying that the SO procedures should be addressed as well?

Comment: Realistically, the problem is rarely ever the canned text, @BoltClock. It's [the stuff folks type after it](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats). The most common reason is, as always, "not programming-related" - if that's actually debatable, it should probably be debated.

Comment: I'm not sure what procedures you mean, @Borodin.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Specifically the procedure whereby [the discussion that you referenced](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284200/custom-off-topic-reasons-sound-defensive-not-concrete/) found the passivity not to be a feature (but also not a problem) but the change to active wording was made anyway

Comment: @Shog9: I don't know whether you're missing my point, but I will reiterate it. I don't believe it's acceptable that every word you type into the site may or may not appear elsewhere in any context that the site software chooses. That's a broad generalisation of the specific  case where, if (and only if) I click on `close` and then `off-topic because` and then `Other`, what I type into the text box will be posted as a comment beneath the original question. There is no indication that this will happen

Comment: Yeah, I got that. So what do you want to happen? Be specific.

Comment: @Shog9: After so many reiterations, I'd like *you* to be specific. What don't you understand about my post? I think it should be clear that you will automatically and implcitly raise a comment under some circumstances.  It's not made clear. What is there to misunderstand? It may be as simple as changing `Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)` to `Other (write a comment explaining what is wrong to be posted beneath the question)` but I don't know the internals of SO and I doubt if that will cover every case

Comment: @Shog9:  It may also help to remove `should be closed` from the `flag` menu if it is truly a duplicate of the top-level `close` menu. It's my position only to explain the symptoms of the problem; I can't offer a solution without access to the site's code

Answer (score 8):

> It seems that sometimes, and without warning, reporting a post may result in a comment beneath that post containing the ideas and reasons that I assumed were private and for the eyes of the moderators only

I think you are being confused between what close votes are for and what other flags are for.  Close votes are *not* the same as moderator attention flags.  Any 3k user can vote to close questions they feel are off-topic on Stack Overflow.  In this context, as many of the comments have pointed out, everything is public.

> [image: Flag vs close]

Even though you can "flag" a post for closure, you're not really flagging it for a moderator at all.  You are actually casting a close vote instead since you have the 3k privilege.  Both the "flag as should be closed" and the "close" link have the same effect of casting a (public) close vote.

> Suppose I want to report a post saying, "My demonstration didn't fail, and she was in bed with me in London while my colleague did it for me, so she didn't even see it"

This is completely irrelevant and should be edited out of the post it appears in.  If you felt it warrants extra attention, you should use a custom moderator flag (and the bottom of the dialog).  Custom moderator flags go directly to moderators, and those messages/details are indeed private among the moderators.

Comment: What you're saying here exemplifies and clarifies a lot. The menu we see after we click `close` is the same as the one after `flag` and `should be closed...`. I would guess it has the same functionality too. This seems horribly wrong, and it's the sort of choice that I imagine would be made so as to relieve pressure from the moderators rather than to provide a consistent intuitive interface. But it compounds my problem. Not only does a comment sometimes appear as a result of my actions *sometimes*, but also the moderators are involved *sometimes*. I would have expected much better

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the text could be even more explicit, but when we select the "Other" category the text says (my emphasis, quoting your quote):

> > - Other (**add a comment** explaining what is wrong)

That doesn't compute with the statement *"I have never noticed a situation where my ideas have been published as a comment"*.

I see that category selection as the system telling us we're going to add a comment. It's kind of DNA of the site, we post Questions, Answers and Comments.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>