# Dealing with "is this a good way to..." questions

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, migration

I recently came across a lot of questions in the form of "is this a good way to achieve a certain outcome", like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772601/is-this-a-good-way-to-display-asynchronous-data) for instance.

Don't these questions belong to the CodeReview site? If so, why isn't question-migration to CodeReview an option? And if not so, how exactly should we answer such questions if the asker's way is the right way? Answering with just "Yes, this is a good approach" doesn't seem like an actual *answer*.

So my question mainly is: what's the proper way of dealing with that kind of questions overall?

*The suggested [duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers) answers an entirely different question. I'm not recommending migration to CR non whatsoever*

Comment: related: [Question closed because yes/no answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773)

Comment: Seems to me that person has done everything right in asking their question. When you have to work this hard to figure out how to close it, maybe that's a good sign you shouldn't be closing it. Perhaps it would be a better fit for Code Review, but regular users cannot migrate questions there, and just because a question is better fit for one site does not make it off-topic elsewhere.

Comment: @gnat thanks for the link! It is related and the accepted answer was actually quiet helpful.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not trying to close it, really! I'm asking what's the right way of answering or dealing with it. As in if answering it with just a "yes" would suffice as an answer. Or perhaps whether that kind of questions doesn't even belong there. Cheers!

Comment: This is like an essay question but missing "why or why not?"  which is basically implied.  I think those kinds of questions are quite useful, for example an answer might talk about it being inefficient or unsafe.  So I think sometimes you might actually want to edit the question to make it not be possible to literally answer with a yes or no.  I'd down vote a one word answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without an objective measure of "good", these questions are primarily opinion based.

As for:

> why isn't question-migration to CodeReview an option?

IIRC, which sites are migration targets depends on the number of successful migrations to those sites. So only the 5 sites with the most successful migrations will be listed. There are either not a lot of requests for migration to Code Review (you can raise a custom flag for sites not in the list) or there are a lot of requests for migration that end up rejected by Code Review.

Note that because this question currently has a bounty it can't be flagged for closure with a regular flag anyway. You need to raise a custom flag on bounty questions that need closing.

<sup>For what it's worth, the OP's example question actually did contain an objective problem: *One problem with my method is the images array might not align with the data array since an image can be fetched out of order.*</sup>

Comment: In many cases there is an objective or better answer. e.g. "no because you are allowing unfiltered user input."

Comment: @Elin - The hypothetical *question* would still be subjective and therefore off topic.

Comment: @Elin [**We never claimed that subjective questions were horrible abominations that should never be asked.** We simply choose to forego those subjective discussions, as there were dozens upon dozens of forums which already catered to them.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) See also: [How can I encourage Stack Overflow to rein in the 'subjective' vigilantes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167516) for more history on the whole subjectivity issue.